# How to solve warning on Mode.com: syntax error at or near "..."?

Tags: sql, warnings

I am new to SQL and through Miss Tina Huang, I came to know Mode.com, a website that provides quite a comprehensive tutorial of SQL. I encountered this problem and dont know how to fix it, can you guys help me:

```
SELECT
  west, 
  midwest, 
  northeast,
  midwest + northeast AS "midwest_northeast_combined"
 FROM tutorial.us_housing_units
 Where west > "midwest_northeast_combined"
```

And then get a warning like this:

```
Looks like something went wrong with your query.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "midwest"
  Position: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"midwest_northeast_combined" column is unknown to the where clause, because in your query `midwest + northeast AS "midwest_northeast_combined"` evaluates after where clause, so you have to repeat it in your where clause:

```
SELECT
  west, 
  midwest, 
  northeast,
  midwest + northeast AS "midwest_northeast_combined"
 FROM tutorial.us_housing_units
 Where west > midwest + northeast
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, the problem has been solved x)